# How to do some action weekly?

Tags: categories, themes, cron

For each new post, I add `News` category.

And I want to `delete this category` from each post after 7 days.
I already know to "delete" the new category but how to run it every week ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try this plugin? 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/scheduled-post-delete/

////

Sorry for my mistake, I understood you wrong. Try by pasting this in your functions.php:

```
function auto_cat_remove() {

    global $post;
    wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 604800, 'remove_news_cat_event', array( $post->ID ) );

}

function remove_news_cat_func( $post_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'news' );
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->term_relationships WHERE object_id = %d AND term_taxonomy_id = %d", $post_id, $category_id ) );
}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'auto_cat_remove' );
add_action( 'remove_news_cat_event', 'remove_news_cat_func' );
```

What this will do is basically schedule event seven days after the post creation. On 7th day, remove_news_cat_func function will run that will remove "news" category from the list of categories assigned to that post.

If you want to test it, you can change 604800 in wp_schedule_single_event to something like 30 and if you do that, 30 seconds after post creation category should be gone.

Note that this function relies on WP-Cron so to fire it, someone actually has to visit the site (this might cause delay with short span of 30 seconds but with days you are fine).

Comment: I don't want to delete post, and I want to delete the category "News" of the post.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Looks good... Looks amazing ! Thank you @OriginalEXE :D

Comment: I have a question : Why do you add_action with `publish_post` ? I don't understand this point.

Comment: publish_post hook is triggered when you create a new post and publish it.

Say you are writing a new article and add it to the news category. You click big blue publish button and the hook fires. 
Hook takes $post object and passes it's id to the schedule event function. Now with schedule event function, I create my own hook that will be fired on the time() + seconds I provide it, and that would be 604800 for 7 days of the week.

On that seventh day, when someone visits your website and triggers wp-cron, system recongizes it has task to do and fires my hook.

Comment: Huh... So the hook is fired for each post ? At the same time when I publish the post, right ? It's also good. However, my approach was to get all posts with the category `News` and fires the hook after 7 days (only one event per week). In your case, if I created 12 posts, I will get 12 schedule event ?

Comment: Yes, that's what it will do.

I fail to see practical value of scheduling event weekly because then posts that were for example published on the 6th day will only stay in the news category for one day.

Comment: Huh !!! Yes, you're right ! Totally right. Otherwise `$wpdb->prepare( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->term_relationships WHERE object_id = $post_id AND term_taxonomy_id = $category_id" )` doesn't work, I had to add **"%d"** and **"%d"** to get this : `$wpdb->prepare( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->term_relationships WHERE object_id = %d AND term_taxonomy_id =  %d", $post_id, $category_id )`

Comment: Yes, correct, good remainder, I updated the answer for future wonderers :)

Comment: It's really weird. It deletes me the wrong category lol. I have multiple categories on the post "Photos, News, Red" but it removes `Photos`. I don't know why... (By the way, the cron works fine)

Comment: Are you sure you added correct name to get_cat_ID function. You input category name there, not a slug, so if your category is named News, have this:
$category_id = get_cat_ID( 'News' );

Comment: Yep, in any case I'm sure I didn't write `get_cat_ID('Photos')` :p

Comment: Lol :) Try specifying the id directly then, $category_id = 55; or whatever id it is. You can see id of the category when you go to category edit screen (just look for the tag id in the url).

Comment: :o It doesn't work ! Even with `id` directly... It awalays removes `Photos` instead of `News` (For information, Photos is the category by default, maybe it's the problem ?)

Comment: Wow, that's really weird. And what if for example you assign only News category to the post, what gets deleted then?

Comment: Nothing happened... :/

Comment: Well call me crazy. I am off to sleep, it's 2am, will try this on my local installation tomorrow and report back here.

Comment: It seems your query doesn't work. I try something else. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. *Thanks @OriginalEXE for the cron.*

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'auto_cat_remove' );
add_action( 'remove_news_cat_event', 'remove_cat_from_post' );

function auto_cat_remove() {
    global $post;
    wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 604800, 'remove_news_cat_event', array( $post->ID ) );
}

function remove_cat_from_post( $post_id ) {

    $term = 419; // Your cat ID
    $taxonomy = "category";

    if ( ! is_numeric( $term ) ) {
        $term = get_term( $term, $taxonomy );
        if ( ! $term || is_wp_error( $term ) )
           return false;
        $term_id = $term->term_id;
    } else {
        $term_id = $term;
    }

    // Get the existing terms and only keep the ones we don't want removed
    $new_terms = array();
    $current_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

    foreach ( $current_terms as $current_term ) {
       if ( $current_term != $term_id )
            $new_terms[] = intval( $current_term );
       }

    return wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $new_terms, $taxonomy );
}
```

Comment: Really great, I am glad you found solution.

I still fail to understand where my code fails but what's important is that you got your answer :)

Comment: I think `$wpdb` must be `$wpdb->prefix` because in my database it's not "wp_" but "wp_new"